# Implementing __delattr__ for a user defined class

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

```
Class MyClasse:
     nom="me"
     age=24
     def __delattr__(self,name)
         if name=="nom":
               raise AttributeError( "you are not allowed")
          else:object.__delattr__(self,name)
A=MyClasse()
del A.age
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2?

Comment: If you're on python3, the right way to do this is calling `super`s `__delattr__`: `super().__delattr__(name)`

Comment: Is this exactly how your code appears? You're missing a colon after your function definition (among other issues...)

Comment: I am using Python 3

Comment: What you have with your MCVE is _not_ an instance attribute... rather a _class_ attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have with your MCVE is not an instance attribute... rather a class attribute. So, `__delattr__` would not be able to find this attribute in `A`'s `__dict__` registry, leading to an `AttributeError` when you call `del` on it.

In this case, you'd need to use `del MyClasse.age` to delete the attribute, which also makes the attribute unaccessible to all instances of `MyClasse`.

---

If you are interested in understanding how to get this working for *instance attributes*, then here's how. With python3, `object` is automatically made the superclass of any class. So, you should be able to invoke its `__delattr__` method using `super`.

```
class foo():
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        print(name)
        super().__delattr__(name)

f = foo()
f.xyz = 123
```

Now, call `del` on the attribute just created.

```
del f.xyz    # works, printing the attribute name as well
xyz
```

Now, try accessing the attribute we've just deleted:

```
f.xyz
AttributeError: 'foo' object has no attribute 'xyz'
```